# MySQL: Join specific table columns (eg.: Table B or C) to the first table (eg.: Table A) based on conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Here's the database tables:

```
User Table
+----+--------------+-----------+-----------+
| id | user_type_id |first_name | last_name |
+----+--------------+-----------+-----------+
|  1 |     1        | Samantha  |   Smith   |
|  2 |     2        | Anne      |  Davidson |
|  3 |     1        | Julius    |   Cesar   |
|  4 |     1        | Arthur    |   Newman  |
+----+--------------+-----------+-----------+

UserType Table
+----+-------------+
| id |    type     |
+----+-------------+
|  1 |  physician  |
|  2 |   patient   |
+----+-------------+

Patient Table
+----+--------------+---------+--------+-----------------+
| id |   user_id    |  height | weight | medical_history |
+----+--------------+---------+--------+-----------------+
|  1 |    2         |   180   |  70    |  severe asthma  |
+----+--------------+---------+--------+-----------------+

Physician Table
+----+--------------+---------------+------------+-----------+------------+
| id |   user_id    | department_id | start_date |  end_date | work_hours |
+----+--------------+---------------+------------+-----------+------------+
|  1 |     1        |       10      | 2021-01-01 |    NULL   |   50.0     |
|  2 |     3        |       5       | 2015-04-27 |    NULL   |   70.5     |
|  3 |     4        |       6       | 2017-12-30 | 2020-03-11|   40.0     |
+----+--------------+---------------+------------+-----------+------------+
```

I want to be able to search a user by their id and display either the User x Patient or User x Physician table columns depending of the user's `user_type_id` value WITHOUT any extra NULL columns.

The result should be like this if `WHERE User.id = 2` (patient):

```
+----+--------------+-----------+-----------+--------+--------+----------------+
| id | user_type_id |first_name | last_name | height | weight | medical_history|
+----+--------------+-----------+-----------+--------+--------+----------------+
|  2 |     2        | Anne      |  Davidson |  180   |  70    |  severe asthma |
+----+--------------+-----------+-----------+--------+--------+----------------+
```

If `WHERE User.id = 4` (physician), the result should look like this:

```
+----+--------------+-----------+-----------+---------------+------------+-----------+------------+
| id | user_type_id |first_name | last_name | department_id | start_date | end_date  | work_hours |
+----+--------------+-----------+-----------+---------------+------------+-----------+------------+
|  4 |     1        | Arthur    |   Newman  |       6       | 2017-12-30 | 2020-03-11|   40.0     |
+----+--------------+-----------+-----------+---------------+------------+-----------+------------+
```

What's the query for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I'd solve it:

```
SELECT u.id, u.user_type_id, u.first_name, u.last_name, 
  p.height, p.weight, p.medical_history, 
  NULL AS department_id, NULL AS start_date, NULL AS end_date, NULL AS work_hours
FROM User AS u JOIN Patient AS p ON u.id=p.user_id
WHERE u.id = ? AND u.user_type_id = 2
UNION
SELECT u.id, u.user_type_id, u.first_name, u.last_name, 
  NULL, NULL, NULL, 
  p.department_id, p.start_date, p.end_date, p.work_hours
FROM User AS u JOIN Physician AS p ON u.id=p.user_id
WHERE u.id = ? AND u.user_type_id = 4;
```

---

Re your comment that you don't want extra NULL columns:

If you want a customized set of columns depending on the user_type_id, that's not possible in a single query. The way SQL works is that the columns in the select-list are fixed before it reads any data. So there's no way to expand, reduce, or change the columns depending on what it finds once it starts reading data.

Your only alternatives involve running more than one query. For example:

---

Alternative 1:

```
SELECT u.id, u.user_type_id, u.first_name, u.last_name, 
  p.height, p.weight, p.medical_history
FROM User AS u JOIN Patient AS p ON u.id=p.user_id
WHERE u.id = ? AND u.user_type_id = 2;

SELECT u.id, u.user_type_id, u.first_name, u.last_name, 
  p.department_id, p.start_date, p.end_date, p.work_hours
FROM User AS u JOIN Physician AS p ON u.id=p.user_id
WHERE u.id = ? AND u.user_type_id = 4;
```

One of the above queries will return 1 row, the other query will return 0 rows. You would then use the result from one that returned 1 row.

---

Alternative 2:

```
SELECT user_type_id FROM User WHERE id = ?;
```

That will tell you what type of user it is. Then you can choose which of the two queries in alternative 1 above to use.

Comment: Using UNION will show Patient AND Physician columns, and the values of either the Patient or Physician columns not meeting the conditions will be NULL. I want those NULL columns to be hidden.

Comment: Handle that in your application code. You don't have to _display_ all the columns.